# Creating Endpoints in Arduino

Tags: arduino, endpoint, sensors

I want to get some data from a few sensors in Arduino and then create some endpoints so i can get the data from the sensors in a web application . Is that possible?

Comment: Where you want to keep this data I mean endpoint will be in arduino itself or on some server/ Live DB ?

Comment: I was thinking to keep in a IOT like Firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Firebase or Thingspeak server to create data endpoint.
First you need to configure wifi module [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) with Arduino then you can use Firebase API or Thingspeak api to send data from arduino to cloud endpoint. [Here](https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-IOT-Using-Arduino-and-ThingSpeak/) is a guide to setup wifi module & send data to thingspeak. 
Once your data is on thingspeak or Firebase you can use their read APIs to read data 
[This](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduino/ref/thingspeakread.html) will help to read data from endpoint.

This repository is particularly for firebase you can check this [FirebaseArduino](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino)